# Unix shell - copy first 300 lines to new file

Tags: unix, io-redirection, unix-head

I've been trying to solve this for days and nothings seems to work.

Copy first 300 lines of a file1 to a new file called file2. This file contains phone number information, already sorted by last name, which is the first field in each record.

```
 head -300 file1 > file2
```

should be the answer but it will not accept.

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: "will not accept"? WHAT is not accepting this?

Comment: `cat -vet file1` Do you see `^M` at the end of each line? then `dos2unix file1` and try again (I'm not sure this is the issue, but a quick test and worth a try). Good luck.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your command line, unless your implementation of `head` is really restrictive and wants to be `head -n 300` instead.  Please include your actual error, so that we can help you understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk` to do this:

```
awk 'NR<=300' file1 > file2
```

The real question is "Why isn't `head` working"... are you getting an error or something?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
head -n 300 < file1 > file2
```